# Excel VBA error on QueryTables.Add & SQL Server 2008R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb, vba

I'm converting an Excel report from accessing data from a SQLAnywhere database to a SQL Server 2008R2 Express database, and I keep getting an error when I run it.  The user enters some items that they want to compare sales movements, and push a button to run the macro.  The macro takes the items, creates a SQL query string, gets the results and displays them.

This worked perfectly with the old DB.  Now with SQL Server, if I run the macro I get a non-helpful "400" error.  If I step through the code, at the end of the "With ActiveSheets.QueryTables.Add(...)" segment it throws a "Run-time error '1004'" at that point.  I'm guessing that there's something about my syntax that isn't supported by the SQL Server or OLE DB connection, but darn if I can see what it is.

I've done a Debug.Print of the SQL query generated, and it runs perfectly if I copy/paste it to a query window in SQL Server Studio.  If I substitute the query for something simple like "select * from DEPT_TAB" it runs fine with the macro.  Creating a table also runs fine, but something about adding an INSERT statement throws it off.

Here's the macro code:

```
Sub SalesHistory()
' Runs SQL from sheet and places into report
' declare method variables
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sConn As String
Dim N1 As Integer
Dim LR As Integer
' create connection string for SQL Server Express
sConn = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
    "Data Source=192.168.0.29\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=STORESQL;" & _
    "User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;"

' stop screen updating while running
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' select SQL sheet and get number of rows in column A
Sheets("SQL").Select
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' loop through column A and create SQL command string
For N1 = 1 To LR
sSQL = sSQL & " " & Range("A" & N1).Value
Next N1

' test print sSQL
Debug.Print sSQL

' select Main sheet, clear report, and activate for new results
Sheets("Main").Select
Range("$A$2:$D$51").ClearContents
Sheets("Main").Activate

' use QueryTables.Add() to get data from server
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=sConn, Destination:=Range("A2))
    .CommandText = sSQL
    .Name = "Movement"
    .FieldNames = False
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With  
' HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN

' restart ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

And here's the query from the worksheet:

```
-- declare variables
DECLARE @StartDate DATE;
DECLARE @Location CHAR(3);
SET @StartDate = '07/29/2012';
SET @Location = 'PAL';
-- create temp table for holding results
CREATE TABLE #tmp_ItemMove (
UPC CHAR(13) NULL,
Brand CHAR(32) NULL,
Descriptor CHAR(32) NULL,
Sales INT NULL);
-- insert zero values for each item so that they always show up in final report
INSERT INTO #tmp_ItemMove 
SELECT OBJ.F01, OBJ.F155, OBJ.F29, 0
FROM OBJ_TAB OBJ
WHERE OBJ.F01 LIKE '' OR
OBJ.F01 LIKE '' OR
OBJ.F01 LIKE '' OR
OBJ.F01 LIKE '' OR
OBJ.F01 LIKE '';
-- insert sales information into temp table
INSERT INTO #tmp_ItemMove
SELECT OBJ.F01, OBJ.F155, OBJ.F29, 
CASE WHEN TRS.F67=0 THEN TRS.F64 ELSE TRS.F67 END
FROM
RPT_ITM_D TRS JOIN OBJ_TAB OBJ ON TRS.F01=OBJ.F01
JOIN TLZ_TAB TLZ ON TRS.F1034=TLZ.F1034
JOIN LNK_TAB LNK ON TRS.F1056=LNK.F1056 AND TRS.F1057=LNK.F1057 AND LNK.F1000=@Location
WHERE (OBJ.F01 LIKE '' OR
OBJ.F01 LIKE '' OR
OBJ.F01 LIKE '' OR
OBJ.F01 LIKE '' OR
OBJ.F01 LIKE '') AND
TRS.F254 >= @StartDate AND
TRS.F1034 BETWEEN 3 AND 4;
-- get final report
-- sum sales history for each item and display
SELECT MAX(UPC),
MAX(Brand),
MAX(Descriptor),
SUM(Sales)
FROM #tmp_ItemMove
GROUP BY UPC, Brand, Descriptor
ORDER BY SUM(Sales) DESC, Brand, UPC;
DROP TABLE #tmp_ItemMove;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just a shot, but try changing your provider from `SQLOLEDB` to `SQLNCLI10.1`.  I think the native SQL provider can handle more syntax than the OLEDB one.

Comment: No luck, but thanks for the tip.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a trace while running the query in the app?  Run a trace that will show all errors and exceptions.  This should show you the exact point of failure.  If there are many transactions going on, you will need to apply some filters. This might be helpful: http://www.bbdevnetwork.com/blogs/debugging-t-sql-and-sql-profiler/ but make sure you turn on errors.

Do the tables have proper permissions?  If you are pasting it into a SSMS window, you may be running as dbo or sa in that window which will allow it to run while the user in excel may have restricted permissions.

You should really make that query into a stored procedure and execute that, because running such a query can have several points of failure, and many drivers will not provide you with any helpful error information.

Comment: I'm logged into the SSMS window as the same user, so permissions should be the same.

Comment: I'd love to make it a stored procedure, but it's a vendor-supplied database and I shouldn't do any writes other than temp tables.  I'll try running a trace, thanks.

Comment: Huh, debug is disabled on the vendor server.  Maybe if I can re-do it without using a temp table...

Comment: That's a tricky situation then.  What you could do is take the statement which you captured, and execute each statement (define only CREATE TABLE #tmp(col int NULL, col2 varchar) as sSQL for example) as its own batch (where possible) and view the result.  This would show you if for example your first insert is failing whereas executing the whole thing will just produce an error which isn't useful.

Comment: Temp table may also be the problem then, do you have access to tempdb?

Comment: Hmm, tempdb might indeed be the problem.  My user login does not have access to tempdb - although it still seems strange that I can run the same query in a SSMS window just fine.  I'll see about getting that permission changed and try again.

Comment: Rats, no luck with adding permission to tempdb.